# Button in AlertDialog not appearing

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have a NeutralButton that should cause an AlertDialog box I have to disappear. This issue is, when the AlertDialog box comes up, the text set appears just fine but the NeutralButton doesn't show at all. I tried it as a Positive and Negative button, but no difference was made. Here's the code:

```
Button infoG1;

    infoG1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.iG1);
    infoG1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder info = new AlertDialog.Builder(game1.this);
            info.setMessage("Text here");
                    info.show();
                    info.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });


        }
    });
```

I would have expected a button with text "Ok" to appear at the bottom of the AlertDialogue box, which causes the box to disappear once the user presses it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't call `setNeutralButton(...)` after your `show()` method. You are doing this, which is causing the problem.

Instead of this:

```
dialog.show();
dialog.setNeutralButton(...);
```

Do this:

```
dialog.setNeutralButton(...);
dialog.show();
```

**Note** that you should put everything above your `dialog.show()`. Otherwise you will have problems.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Button infoG1;

    infoG1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.iG1);
    infoG1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder info = new AlertDialog.Builder(game1.this);
            info.setMessage("Text here");
            info.setNeutralButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
                    info.show();
          }
    });
```